# Hide standard app page header

Tags: header

I want to hide the standard header on the app page as shown in the image. Please help me how to do it.

.[image]

Thanks.

Comment: click on gearIcon-->editpage and click on that header and try to remove.try it once.Iam not sure

Comment: Hi @AnnappaPH, the banner is not on the layout once I edit the page.

Comment: I posted a detailed solution to a similar problem [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/260858/hide-standard-page-header-in-custom-lightning-app-page/267937#267937)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to hide the header bu creating css file and uploaded it on the Static resources then call the file in lightning component.

Comment: This doesn't really provide enough information to be useful to other people with the same question. Would you care to elaborate?