# Hide Standard Page Header in Custom Lightning App page

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-apps, lightning-design-system

Is there a way to hide the page header in a custom Lightning App shown below ?
This banner is not available in the Edit page section.

I have selected 'One region Template' and added just one Lightning component.

[image]

But after saving the header comes by default which I want to remove.

[image]

PS: I was able to remove the header by putting the display as none as shown below. But don't know which standard class to refer in css

[image]

Comment: Can you include more details like What component you have added in your home page?

Comment: Please check.. I know for a fact that using css, we can remove the header.. But just don't know which standard class to refer..

Comment: Can you paste minimal required code of your component by editing your question?

Comment: I have not added any code from the LC as I don't think it is relevant. You can consider any component for Eg: a LC only showing a tabular list of sObjects.

Comment: you can use CSS styling to hide a standard component element and this should be pointed to particular element If you are applying the CSS on parent page because it may changes the standard look and feel of the standard component.

Comment: Thanks.. I know I can use a CSS styling (See the last part of the quest).. Just don't know how to refer the element in CSS

Comment: Another option that you can do is to create a lightning component tab without creating a page through app builder, it wont add the section you are talking about

Answer (score 13):

In your lightning component bundle, allow Lightning Tab as a target:

```
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__Tab</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Go to `Setup > Tabs > Lightning Component Tabs`. Click `New`, then choose your component.

Use your newly created `Lightning Component Tabs` instead of the `Lightning Page Tabs`.

Comment: This is currently the best way to remove the header from "single-component" applications. Note that this will leave the developer to create any layout within the component.

Comment: Do lightening component tabs can receive params like lightning comp. apps? Because if not, it's a big consideration if to use this solution.

Comment: Perfect - I should have used a Tab in the first place.

Comment: Please note that "My Domain" has to be enabled for this to work. I found that out the hard way. (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=aura_add_cmp_lex.htm&type=5)

Comment: This is non starter. Using this approach you cannot add any list views or other stuff into your template...

Comment: It resolves the problem of default header but as here is commented, the page will be incompatible with Lightning App Builder and there is no customization possible, just show the component you chose.

Answer (score 11):

I know the name of the class in question is "slds-page-header".

As an example, I've edited my own page to get rid of the header by changing the css specific to that class (this first picture is the "before"):

[image: Before Style edit]

And after editing the style by adding "display: none" for that class (slds-page-header):

[image: slds-page-header style edited]

And now the header is gone from my page. How do I add this css style change to the lightning app page? This [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/219081/hide-standard-app-page-header) says to upload the css as a static resource and call the resource in the lightning web component. I'm not sure how to do that. Anyone?

Update:

A much more restrictive change to the css would look like this:

header.flexipageHeader.slds-page-header.uiBlock.oneAnchorHeader {
    display: none;
}

Update #2:

Ameer Awad's answer seems to apply only to aura components whereas I am using lightning web components. However, his answer pointed me in the right direction. I uploaded a static resource as he suggested, and then in the .js for my component, I added these imports:

```
import HideLightningHeader from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/HideLightningHeader';
import { loadStyle, loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
```

And then in the connectedCallBack() method:

```
    connectedCallback() {
    loadStyle(this, HideLightningHeader)
}
```

No more header in my lightning app! Cool!!

Comment: Or, at least, slds-page-header is ONE of the classes involved here.

Comment: While the component that has this logic is loading, the default header is visible. If you have slow network connection, there are enough time being visible so this solution offers bad UX but it resolves the problem and it will be compatible with Lightning App Builder to drag & drop any components you want there.

Comment: This solution (lwc) worked for me - thank you

Answer (score 10):

---

### 6/15/21 Update

Static Resource solution updated to work with Summer '21 Release.

**New Version**

```
[app_flexipage-header_header-host]{
    display:none;
}
```

**Old Version**

```
header.flexipageHeader.slds-page-header.uiBlock.oneAnchorHeader { 
    display: none;
}
```

---

Following up from previous answers, you can add a style sheet as a static resource and reference it in your component. The way to do that is to open up any text editor, I used notepad on my HP. You then insert the following code:

```
[app_flexipage-header_header-host]{ 
    display: none;
}
```

You can save this as whatever you like followed by .css, I named my file NoHeader.css

Next upload it to static resources on Salesforce: [image]

Then, anywhere in your component add the following snippet:

```
<ltng:require styles="{!$Resource.NoHeader}"/>
```

That should be it!

Comment: While this works, it appears to hide it from every app page. Is there a way to limit it to a single app page?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue recently, I did try to change the Lightning App Tab to a Lightning Component Tab. But this will restrict us from editing our Lightning App Page via the Lightning App Builder.

Instead, I created a custom LWC for that, whereby in my component I'm hiding the standard banner on the lightning app page.

```
.slds-page-header.flexipageHeader { 
    display: none;
}
```

You may have a reference to my component [here](https://github.com/xdf29/XD_Custom_Lightning_Header_Project). Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented an app "Unlock Global Header" to hide the global header on record pages.

Check it out: https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N4V00000HqGBiUAN