# Hide Standard Page Header

Tags: lightning-web-components, static-resources

I know this question is duplicate of the following: [Hide Standard Page Header in Custom Lightning App page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/260858/hide-standard-page-header-in-custom-lightning-app-page).

The problem is that the solution of creating a static resource and using it in the LWC stopped working for me overnight. Until a few days ago it worked perfectly.

My code is the following:

Static Resource:

```
header.flexipageHeader.slds-page-header.uiBlock.oneAnchorHeader {
  display: none !important;
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StaticResource xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <cacheControl>Public</cacheControl>
    <contentType>text/css</contentType>
</StaticResource>
```

LWC:

```
import NoHeader from "@ salesforce / resourceUrl / NoHeader";
import {loadStyle} from "lightning / platformResourceLoader";

  connectedCallback () {
    loadStyle (this, NoHeader);
}
```

I know that if I put Lightning_Tab in the LWC XML and creating a Lightning Component Tab this problem is corrected, but I need a solution like the static resource because I need the tab to reload when I return to it from another tab and this does not happen with the lightning components tabs.

Has a Salesforce update affected this solution? Because the code is still the same as before, but it no longer works.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The static resource solution to hide the header no longer works, apparently.

The solution that I found so that the Header disappears and so that the tab reloads every time I return to it is the following: In the component, specifically in the XML, I put  lightning__HomePage

Then in Setup -> Lightning App I created a Home Page and dragged my LWC component.