# How to hide white background on LWC Component load?

Tags: apex, lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-design-system

When you load an lwc component that is a screenAction, when you click a button to activate component or is triggered via a connectedCallback, this alway appears.

How would you hide the white background?

I know you can do an slds-hide a a specific Div, but what would this count as?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't do this in an approved manner. It's baked in to the modal's styles. You can use loadStyle to [globally override](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/267937/2984) CSS (e.g. the modal's background), but this may be blocked in a future update. Ideally, you should just accept that the background is a necessary limitation of the platform. Any workaround you may do for now will not likely last for long into the future.

Comment: Thank you for the response. It just creates a little bit of an awkward UX.